# Bind dynamic choices to ModelForm in Django

Tags: django

I'm trying to bind a dynamic list of choices to a ModelForm. The form is rendered correctly. However, when using the form with a POST Request, I get an empty form back. My goal is to save that form into the database (form.save()). Any help would be much appreciated.

**Model**

I'm using a multiple choice select field ( https://github.com/goinnn/django-multiselectfield )

```
from django.db import models
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

class VizInfoModel(models.Model):

     tog = MultiSelectField()
     vis = MultiSelectField()
```

**Forms**

```
class VizInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = VizInfoModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self,choice,*args,**kwargs):
        super(VizInfoForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['tog'].choices = choice 
        self.fields['vis'].choices = choice
```

**View**

Choices are passed from the view when instantiating the form.

```
def viz_details(request):

    options = []
    headers = request.session['headers']
    for header in headers :
        options.append((header, header))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VizInfoForm(options, request.POST)
        #doesnt' get into the if statement since form is empty! 
        #choices are not bounded to the model although the form is perfectly rendered           
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/upload')
    else:
        #this works just fine
        form = VizInfoForm(options) 
        return render(request, 'uploads/details.html', {'form': form})
```

**Template**

```
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}

         <p>Choose variables to toggle between</p>
        {{ form.tog }}

        <br></br>
        <p>Choose variable to be visualized</p>
        {{ form.vis }}

        <br></br>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're saying Django doesn't get into your `if request.method == 'POST'` block.

This tells us that you're not sending your request through the POST method. Your template probably has an error in it, maybe you haven't specified the method on your `form`, or you made your button to just be a link instead of a submit ?

Show your template so we can say more, unless this was enough to solve your question !

Comment: It gets into the if request.method == 'POST' block. If I print its content, everything looks fine. Problem comes when instantiating the form as VizInfoForm(options, request.POST), where I get an empty form which doesn't go through the validation if statement.